# MIsaligned line

Tags: xetex, minipage

Why "Misaligned" line is not aligned right using the same margin as other minipages?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flushright}
        Misaligned    
    \end{flushright}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
        \section{more}
                \blindtext
        \section{more}
            \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}        
        \section{foo}
            \blindtext
        \section{foo}
            Some
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Updated code

Comment: `.95 + .65 + .3 = 1.9` is larger than text width!! You could use `.3` to each one.

Comment: also you have word spaces between your minipages so the total width is more than the sum of each minipage.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the code with your comments

Comment: now you have a paragraph indent, a box of .7\textwidth, a word space, 4em space a box of .3\textwidth, so they clearly can not fit on a line, what layout do you intend?

Comment: Because the minipage on the right is out of margin. Load `\usepackage{showframe}` to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Sigur, what's the box at the right? Margin-notes? How could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fit those two minipages with width `0.7\textwidth` and `0.3\textwidth`, you have to make sure that the second one follows exactly after the first one, with no spaces around them, that is, in front, between, etc...

But now, in this case, it is too glued. If you want spaces between them, you have to decrease the width a little bit (and maybe put `\hfill` between).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        Misaligned    
    \end{flushright}

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
        \section{more}
                \blindtext
        \section{more}
            \blindtext
    \end{minipage}% <---- important
%    \qquad
%    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}        
        \section{foo}
            \blindtext
        \section{foo}
            Some
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I'd like to keep the minipages separated by 2 quads. What's the box at the right?

Comment: It is the margin notes area. If you increase ` \textwidth` it would move to right. You have to set it up to zero width (`\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0in}`).